# Ext JS grid panel spacer removal

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am quite new to Ext JS 4 and I have created a Panel with a fixed column. There seems to be some kind of bug(as read on some forum) and if I make a column fixed, a *spacer*(xtype: tbspacer) is automatically inserted at its top, ruining the table's alignment(if it is just a matter of bad configuration, please let me know). What I would like to do is to remove that spacer.

In order to do this, I have to select it, but it doesn't have a "static" id, meaning that if I make any modifications to the view, the spacer gets another id, so I need a method to select it without making use of the id. I have tried doing something like this:

```
list.query('.tbspacer')[0].setHeight(0);
```

where `list` is the panel. But it doesn't seem to work. The `list.query()` method returns an empty array. I get the same issue when trying to select a *textfield*.

Am I missing something, or is it just another bug?

This is how I create the locked column(nothing special):

```
{
  header: headerName, 
  dataIndex: i, 
  locked: true
}
```

**EDIT** Here is also a screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT** That spacer shouldn't have existed in the first place, it was(maybe still is?) in that version of the framework. See my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223169/extjs-4-1-gridpanel-missplaced-column). I will mark the only answer here as accepted because it seemed to provide a fix to the problem mentioned in this question.

Comment: Can u provide your code? And probably a screenshot or feeble so we can see exactly what's happening.

Comment: @sha I edited my question with some code(I don't know what exactly should I select from it). As for the screenshot, I couldn't make one with a good quality. The issue is that all the data in the fixed column is with one row below the others.

Comment: What is `locked`? I can't find it in the ExtJs docs. If you need to disable resizing of the column - use `resizable: false`

Comment: @sha It seems to be missing from their docs, but it makes a column fixed, meaning that it won't disappear when I scroll to the right, it remains on the first position, no matter what.

Comment: I now understand what you're trying to achieve, but without screenshot can't really get what's going wrong... (Replace `header` with the `text` btw)

Comment: @sha I have added a screenshot. I am sorry for the huge delay, I worked on something else and forgot about this. Now it's bugging me again. Can you please take another look?

Comment: Looks ugly :) Try to minimize code so you have a short sample that can be posted to fiddle or somewhere else and shows your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you’re doing a wrong query. It should be just `tbspacer`, without the dot. Second, instead of `setHeight(0)`, why not just `destroy` it?

```
list.query('tbspacer')[0].destroy();
```

Comment: Do you happen to know why it is even created? Is it a 4.1 bug?

Comment: No idea. But there’s plenty of bugs in Ext JS, so this may well be one. On the other hand, if `locked` is a private API, you can’t complain about “bugs” if you use it. You’d better ask on the Sencha forums.