# ExtJS 4.1 GridPanel missplaced column

Tags: javascript, extjs4.1

I have a GridPanel, but, as you can see, the first column(which is `locked`) is not aligned like the other ones.

Is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

**EDIT:** Here are some snippets regarding the columns:

```
 initComponent: function(){
     this.renderTo = this.divId;
     this.status = "normal";
     Ext.Array.insert(this.columns,0,this.cols);
     this.columns = this.cols;
         this.callParent(); 
    }
```

and the `cols` object looks like this:

```
for(var i in params){
                if(i != config.staticColumn)
                cols.push({header: headers[i], dataIndex: i});
                else{
                    cols.push({header: headers[i], dataIndex: i, locked: true});
                }
            }
```

That space is actually:

```
<div id="gridview-1323-spacer" style="height: 17px"></div>
```

I don't know what this means or why it gets created in the first place.

Comment: Can you post some code please.

Comment: @gunnx I have added some lines. Any ideas?

Comment: does that first cell in the first column receive any data?

Comment: @gunnx If by this you mean the empty cell, no, t doesn't receive any data. It's `id` contains the word `spacer`, so I wonder if it isn't actually a `tbspacer` inserted there...

Comment: Have you tried giving that cell the value of "&nbsp;"

Comment: @gunnx The cell is not created by me. As you can see in the screenshot, the cells on the first column, are displayed **almost** a row under the others. It doesn't insert a new cell: the white space on top is smaller than a normal cell. In the screenshot I tried to select the first row, and this is the result. Somehow that thing is inserted automatically.

Comment: inspect the dom to see what that spacer element is, maybe post it on here so we can see what it i

Comment: @gunnx Please see the edit. I hope this is what you've asked.

Comment: There is a similar thread on sencha forums, why not have a read and see if it helps. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198988-4.1.0-Locked-columns-in-infinite-grid-break-scroll-synchronization

Comment: @gunnx I don't know if it's the same problem or not. It might be. But the "possible fix" provided didn't change anything. Some other hints, maybe?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13118/discussion-between-gunnx-and-dragos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with ExtJS(like a few others). I have asked for support on their forum, but no answer was provided fast enough to be useful(the last time I checked - maybe a year or so ago there was still no answer).

In the meantime I have stopped working with this framework and have not checked for another fix.